# soldering wires between two points on a perfboard

Tags: soldering

I have two IC holders and I want to connect a pin from IC1 to a pin from IC2 using a wire.
my current approach is soldering the IC holders and later just reheating the solder on a pin, sticking in a 30awg wire and letting it cool again.
the problem is sometimes it doesn't cool down and neatly as it was before, and I'm wondering if the connection is as good as it was...

is there some better technique?

Answer (score 4):

That's probably because the wire isn't clean. Use extra solder with flux kernel, the flux cleans the wire (reduces any oxidation). The best thing is **tinned wire**, even older solder should flow up that wire easily.
Tinned wire is also easy to lay out on the perfboard: just hold it/heat it with your soldering iron, and the solder will flow nicely over the pad and wire.